# SurfaceView flicker on setVisiblity() in 2.0 and later version

Tags: android

Got this issue developing a game application.
**Main concept**:
We have an activity with layout set to it by **setContentView**.
Layout has a SurfaceView, which is used to draw some additional graphics (transition between different screens).
Problem is that on 1.5 and 1.6 everything works prefectly fine.
But testing on 2.0 and greater version of andorid shown a issue:
At the moment when we use **setVisiblity**(true/false) on our SurfaceView screen flickers with black.

**EDITED:** Seems like starting from 2.0 any changes to order of views in hierarchy cause some flickering. 
Tried removing view using **(ViewGroup).removeView(myView)** - same results like in **setVisiblility()**

 Checked sources, in both methods **invalidate()->invalidateChild()->invalidateChildInParent()** are called.
 May be some problem in SDK methods?

Also noted another issue on 2.0/2.0.1/2.1-update1. If from activity with layout and surfaceView we start another activity by **startActivity/startActivityForResult()** after we get back from that activity, canvas of the surfaceView will be valid all right, but it will be just black. And drawing on that canvas will not be shown. Reseting holder of surface in callback methods didn't help at all.

If anyone happen to know workarounds for these issue, I'll be very grateful.